# Photoshop document settings for iPhone and Android App development

Tags: android, iphone, photoshop

I am working on a concept for both iPhone and Android app. App contains images, text and buttons.
So far everything going well in terms of creative, but I assume there is going to be a big leap into technical part of development soon, so im feeling little bit nervous about that and im asking you for help.

I am using **Photoshop** to create App screens, buttons and everything… and of course, vector and smart objects within.

I am not sure exact what DPI i suppose to use, 72, 163 or 326…?

However, I do know the iPhone 4 resolution is 640x960 pixels, and I wonder how my PSD document should look like?

Can you guys help me with this new document settings for iPhone first, please:

Width: 640 pixels
Height: 940 pixels
Resolution: 72 ????  pixels/inch
Color mode: RGB Color  8 bit.

Than I would need the same kind of info for Android platform, please.

And if there are some additional things i should know in advance before or after, please give me a hint, I really appreciate!

Thank you!
Cheers!

Comment: Which Android device are you targeting? Practically every Android device has a different DPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure exactly what DPI is best, but I can share my experience so far. I just created my first mobile design comp and tested it on the iPhone at 72 DPI and that is not large enough (for the 4th gen model at least) The 326 setting seems to work for my comp, so that is what I would suggest you try. It seems to be the consensus opinion based on what I have heard in talking to the guys I work with who is a developer.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

I've done visual design for about 10-15 iPhone Applications.
Don't set the document to the ppi of the phone as everyone above is suggesting. That will just make your work impossibly small to work with on the computer screen.

- **16 bit color** - 
  Read about [gradient banding](http://nomorebanding.com), then use the Photoshop action at the link to fix.
- **Disabled Color Managment** Read this http://bjango.com/articles/photoshop/
- **Uncheck "Convert for sRGB" for PNG in File > Save for Web**

Other than that no other settings are very important. 
You want snap to pixels turned on for the vector shapes tool. This comes default in CS5&6.

Again don't set the PPI (DPI) of your photoshop document to the same as the device. Leave that at whatever the default is (72). This doesn't affect the artwork resolution. You want 1px on your screen to equal 1px on the iPhone screen when you are designing. so leave this setting alone.